# Ruby Debugging Open Source Libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I would like to debug and possibly contribute to some open source gems but am fairly new to Ruby and Rails. What is the best way to go in and start setting breakpoints, etc?

Right now I just use ruby-debug for my own code and inspect variables mostly.

Comment: I'm already using the debugger, I'm more confused how to do it with other libraries. 

Right now the only way I know how is to clone the git repository, make changes and then reinstall the gem and/or restart the server every time.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to debug using Rails without restarting Rails every time. Using a Gemfile with Bundler is actually very painless for using libs both in Rails and standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the ruby-debugger gem. Make sure you have have [rubygems](http://rubygems.org) installed, then do

```
gem install ruby-debug
```

Then, add the line

```
require 'ruby-debug'
```

to your sourcecode to load the library, and add the keyword 'debugger' wherever you want to set a breakpoint. Now, whenever you call the code in question, it'll drop to the debugging console when it reaches the breakpoint - press h to see a list of options to see what you can do from there. Obviously, remember to remove your breakpoints and the require statement after you're done!

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing now. Thought there were maybe some different tools I wasn't aware of.

Comment: aah, i'm sorry - i missed that bit of your post. bundler ('gem install bundler') will make it easier to manage the gem dependencies in your own projects, so if you want to rely on your patched version of a gem, rather than the canonical version, you can specify this and have bundler keep track of the dependency for you.

Comment: In terms of contributing back to projects, the standard workflow (assuming the project is hosted on github) seems to be - fork the git repository for the project ,make your changes on your fork (including tests for any changes), then submit a pull request to the source project. The maintainer can then pull the changes from your fork and include them in a release. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that you can't edit the libraries without having to restart the Rails server. Oh well. Bundler does make it easier I've found, just change the version string to :path => "/some/dir"